# Rewrite two (or multiple) urls to one new url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite two old urls:

```
www.example.com/Car-Systems/ford.html
www.example.com/mobile/new-car-systems/ford.html
```

New target url:

```
www.newexample.com/new-car-systems/ford.html
```

One rewrite is actually pretty simple:

```
RewriteRule ^www\.example\.com/Car-Systems/ford\.html$ /www.newexample.com/new-car-systems/ford.html? [L,R=301]
```

But how do I get the second one in only one rewrite? **Or do I always have to create 2 rules for each rewrite?**

Comment: What do you mean by *for each rewrite*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single rule that you have wouldn't work either, unless you're visiting those pages as: `http://some.domain.com/www.example.com/mobile/new-car-systems/ford.html`. Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(mobile/new-)?car-systems/ford.html$ /new-car-systems/ford.html [NC,L,R=301]
```